# How to search in an array of hashes by each character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an array of hashes:

```
2.6.0 :132 > a = [{:id=>51, :company_name=>"231421AAAAA company"},
{:id=>52, :company_name=>"tregfsd"}, {:id=>53, :company_name=>"aaaaa"},
{:id=>54, :company_name=>"zzzzzz"}, {:id=>55, :company_name=>"bbbbb"}]
```

How to find data in case when user provide incomplete params like `company_name = "231421"` it should return

```
 => {:id=>51, :company_name=>"231421AAAAA company"}
```

I was trying to use `a.detect { |d| d[:company_name] == '231421' }` but I've got `=> nil`

What should I use to do search it without giving the whole `company_name` ?

Comment: `#include?` is what you want

Comment: You say "...incomplete params *like*...". What do you mean by "like"?  Specifically, what is the *rule* for determining if a value has been abbreviated, and if it has been, the *rule* for modifying it? How do we know that  `"tregfsd"` should not be changed to `"tregfsd123"`? Is it only the literal `"231421"` you are looking for as a value? Do you wish to change every value `"231421"` to  `"231421AAAAA company"`? Please clarify by editing your answer (rather than elaborating in a comment). Also,  `company_name = "231421"` should be `:company_name => "231421"`.

Comment: Please see "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one record:

```
a.find{ |company| company[:company_name].include?(company_name) }
#=> { :id => 51, :company_name => "231421AAAAA company" }
```

If you want more than one match record, use `select` instead of `find`:

```
company_name = 'a'
a.select{ |company| company[:company_name].include?(company_name) }
#=> [
#     { :id => 51, :company_name => "231421AAAAA company" },
#     { :id => 53, :company_name => "aaaaa" }
#   ]
```

Comment: That's great, do you know how to show only id for each searched value?

Comment: @mr_muscle You can use `pluck` method:  `a.select{ |company| company[:company_name].include?(company_name) }.pluck(:id)`

Comment: `include?` is good, but keep in mind it finds in any position, not just the start.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`String#start_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F)

```
a.detect { |d| d[:company_name].start_with?('231421') }
```